# Batch script command to filter record in csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a CSV file with format as below

[Input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vi8y.png)

I need to have a new file with the following filter condition to the csv file

1. Filter out all the measure values <=0
2. If Measure value >1, then duplicate the rows the number of times the measure value and increment the value of datetime field by 1 seconds for each duplicated records and reset the measure values to 1.

expected result be [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo1zo.png)

can someone assist on this please?

I tried this

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set input_file=input.csv
set output_file=output.csv

(for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%input_file%") do (
    set line=%%a
    set measure values=!line:*,=!
    if "!measure values!" gtr "0" (
        echo !line!
    )
)) > "%output_file%"
```

I tried the above script but it copies the entire records into the output file.

Input file

```
Datetime,Measure Names,Category,Measure Values
03/14/2023 16:33:44,Sales ,Table,1
03/14/2023 16:33:44,Amt,Table,0
03/14/2023 16:33:44,Profilt,Table,1
03/14/2023 16:33:44,Qty,Table,2
```

Expected output in csv format

```
Datetime,Measure Names,Category,Measure Values
03/14/2023 16:33:44,Qty,Table,1
03/14/2023 16:33:45,Qty,Table,1
```

Comment: Include the `csv` *as text* in your question. A picture, of how EXCEL (or another spreadsheet program) *interprets*  it, doesn't show us what we need to know to help you. We need to see the original data.

Comment: As above. Please [Edit] your question to include, formatted as code, the content of the CSV files currently shown as tabular data in GUI software.

Comment: If you're going to open Excel anyway, why not write something in VBA?

Comment: @Stephan, Sure. I made the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that a batch file is the best for this but:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set input_file=input.csv
set output_file=output.csv

(
    REM Loop through the lines of the input file, splitting each line into tokens using commas as delimiters.
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("%input_file%") do (
        call :set_variables "%%a" "%%b" "%%c" "%%d"
        
        REM Check if the value is greater than 1.
        if !value! gtr 1 (
            REM Loop from 1 to the value, incrementing by 1 each time.
            for /l %%i in (1, 1, !value!) do (
                set /a seconds=%%i - 1
                REM Call the subroutine to add seconds to the date and time and set the new_datetime variable.
                call :add_seconds_to_datetime !datetime! !seconds!
                REM Output the new row with the updated date and time and a value of 1.
                echo !new_datetime!,!measure!,!category!,1
            )
        )
    )
) > "%output_file%"

exit /b

:set_variables
set "datetime=%~1"
set "measure=%~2"
set "category=%~3"
set "value=%~4"
goto :eof

REM Subroutine to add seconds to a date and time string in MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss format.
:add_seconds_to_datetime
setlocal
set datetime_str=%1
set seconds_to_add=%2

REM Split the date and time string into date and time.
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%d in ("%datetime_str%") do (
    set date=%%d
    set time=%%e
)

REM Combine the date and time into an ISO 8601 format.
set "datetime_fmt=!date!T!time!"

REM Use PowerShell to parse the date and time, add the specified number of seconds, and output the new date and time in MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss format.
for /f %%t in ('powershell -noprofile -command "&{[datetime]::ParseExact('%datetime_fmt%', 'MM/dd/yyyyTHH:mm:ss', $null).AddSeconds(%seconds_to_add%).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')}"') do (
    set new_datetime=%%t
)

REM Set the new_datetime variable in the parent scope and exit the subroutine.
endlocal & set "new_datetime=%new_datetime%"
exit /b
```

input.csv :

```
04/13/2023 16:45:33, Sales, Table,1
04/13/2023 16:45:33, Amt, Table,0
04/13/2023 16:45:33, Profit, Table,1
04/13/2023 16:45:33, Qty, Table,2
```

python example:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def process_csv(input_file, output_file):
    # Open the input and output CSV files
    with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)  # Create a CSV reader for the input file
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)  # Create a CSV writer for the output file

        # Loop through each row in the input CSV file
        for row in reader:
            date_str, measure, category, value_str = row  # Extract the values from the row
            value = int(value_str)  # Convert the value to an integer

            # If the value is greater than 1, process the row
            if value > 1:
                # Parse the date and time from the date string
                date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

                # Loop from 0 to value-1, incrementing by 1 each time
                for i in range(value):
                    # Add 'i' seconds to the date and time
                    new_date = date + timedelta(seconds=i)

                    # Convert the new date and time back to a string
                    new_date_str = new_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

                    # Write the new row to the output CSV file
                    writer.writerow([new_date_str, measure, category, 1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = "input.csv"
    output_file = "output.csv"
    process_csv(input_file, output_file)  # Call the process_csv function with the input and output file paths
```

and you run it like:
*python pyfile.py input.csv output.csv*

powershell version:

```
$input_file = "input.csv"
$output_file = "output.csv"

$csv_content = Import-Csv -Path $input_file -Header 'DateTime', 'Measure', 'Category', 'Value' -Delimiter ','

$result = @()

foreach ($row in $csv_content) {
    $value = [int]$row.Value
    if ($value -gt 1) {
        $datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($row.DateTime, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $value; $i++) {
            $new_datetime = $datetime.AddSeconds($i).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
            $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
                'DateTime' = $new_datetime
                'Measure'  = $row.Measure
                'Category' = $row.Category
                'Value'    = 1
            }
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path $output_file -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

to use the powershell version, you'll need to turn on execution privileges using *Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process*
You may not want to turn that on... it's off by default for a reason.
You execute by running *.\process_csv.ps1* where pocess_csv.ps1 is your ps file name.

Comment: Thank You, It works however the output comes as only for the measure values > 1 .all other records are filtered out along with the header lines. So the result is like "  +,Qty ,Table,1 ","
+,Qty,Table,1"

Comment: Is it because I need to install Powershell or something?

Comment: hmmmm can you remove the time from the CSV so it's like this: 04/13/2023, Sales, Table,1 and see if that works?

Comment: I will need the timestamp to differentiate the records.

Comment: Will writing this in python be easy than the batch script?@Shawn

Comment: when I typed in the input file I neglected the time stamp and that worked, so there must be something wrong with the powershell sort

Comment: I added a python example to my answer. The caveat is that python must be installed but I tested it working. If this works please accept my answer.

Comment: I also added a pure powershell version

Comment: Thank You so much. Let me go over my code once again. Python script worked. :)